# extjs el.up[].dom null or not an object

Tags: extjs

i am developing an application using extjs i am doing almost every thing dynamically.like creating and adding nodes to a tree. creating a tab panel.creating n number of windows and grids.now every now and then i am getting error like extjs el.up[].dom null or not an object, el.cache[].event null or not an object...i am not sure why these thing comes..does any one have any idea about this?please help

Comment: Use Firebug and `ext-all-debug.js` instead of `ext-all.js`.

Answer (score 2):

These things usually happen when events or actions are associated directly with a tree node, and not cleaned up when a node gets removed or refreshed.

Are you refreshing the tree or reloading nodes ever?

Turn on FireBug and use "Break on Error".  When the error occurs and you are debugging, check out the stack to see what action was trying to be performed.  Make sure you are using ext-all-debug.js, as the commenter said above.